# Powershell: Why will this foreach loop not output?

Tags: powershell

I have the following simple script:

```
write-output "Calculating Mod Dates . . ."
$path = 'C:\Users\Server\SERVER\Online'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path '$path' -include "*"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $ModDate = Get-Item $importfile | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
    $CurrentDate = Get-Date
    $differece = ($CurrentDate - $ModDate).TotalSeconds
    write-output "$importfile - $differece seconds ago."
}
```

However, while the first `write-output` command works, the second does not. Why is this?

Comment: The only reason would be that there are no files returned by the previous line.  Have you tried to debug the script within ISE?

Comment: The variables all get set though, there are two files in the dir. All debug options are faded.

Comment: Did you use break points within PowerShell ISE?

Comment: Yes. I could turn those on and off in the debug menu, but the actual debugger tools are greyed

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong use of single quotes in third line: '$path' evaluates to
string literal $path, which is not likely an actual, umm, path.

Comment: This.  And I would recommend $myPath to avoid any silly conflicts.  Also the -include "*" is not needed.

Comment: removing the quotes causes a Get-Item error `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'path' because it is null.` If I remove the `-include *` it says `Cannot find path `C:\Users\Server\SERVER\Appdata\$path` This leads me to think it is treating the `$path` as a subpath instead of a whole path. How do I make it handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Poorman's Debug session approach - using the ISE  and /or VSCode

You have syntax errors and stuff in there that is not populated and out of place.
Write-Output is the default, so no real need to specify it.
Use single quote for simple strings, double for expanding variables, specific formatting scenarios using say the -f.

```
# write-output 'Calculating Mod Dates . . .'
'Calculating Mod Dates . . .'

# What I am showing here is called variable squeezing.
# It assigns to the variable while output to the screen so you can see what is being populated.
# remove the far left and far right parens to eliminate all the extra output
($path = 'E:\Temp')
($files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path) 

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    # This is not doing anything as $importfile is not declared or populate anywhere that you have shown.
    # $ModDate = Get-Item $importfile | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
    # This should be 
    ($ModDate = (Get-Item -Path $file.FullName).LastWriteTime)
    ($CurrentDate = Get-Date)
    ($difference = ($CurrentDate - $ModDate).TotalSeconds)
    # write-output "$importfile - $differece seconds ago."
    "$($file.Name) - $difference seconds ago."
}


# Results

 'Calculating Mod Dates . . .'
Calculating Mod Dates . . .

 ($path = 'E:\Temp')
E:\Temp

 ($files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path) 


    Directory: E:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        1/14/2019   3:42 PM                Reports
-a----        2/25/2019  10:27 AM          81966 Best-practices.jpg
-a----        2/25/2019  10:28 AM          82919 computer_speed.jpg
-a----        3/19/2019   3:34 PM             26 csv1.csv
...                                                                                     



 foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    ($ModDate = (Get-Item -Path $file.FullName).LastWriteTime)
    ($CurrentDate = Get-Date)
    ($difference = ($CurrentDate - $ModDate).TotalSeconds)
    "$($file.Name) - $difference seconds ago."
}


Monday, January 14, 2019 3:42:40 PM
Wednesday, March 27, 2019 11:55:21 AM
6207161.4845608
Reports - 6207161.4845608 seconds ago.
Monday, February 25, 2019 10:27:37 AM
Wednesday, March 27, 2019 11:55:21 AM
2597263.7171875
Best-practices.jpg - 2597263.7171875 seconds ago.
Monday, February 25, 2019 10:28:26 AM
Wednesday, March 27, 2019 11:55:21 AM
2597215.0719793
computer_speed.jpg - 2597215.0719793 seconds ago.
Tuesday, March 19, 2019 3:34:04 PM
Wednesday, March 27, 2019 11:55:21 AM
678077.1822375
csv1.csv - 678077.1822375 seconds ago.
Tuesday, March 19, 2019 3:34:34 PM
Wednesday, March 27, 2019 11:55:21 AM
678047.2243663
...
```